# MYSQL Select many to many

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, many-to-many

I was working with two tables: comment, user

comment table had a recipient field holding a user id

Now we must change the comment/recipient to a many-many relationship as multiple users can receive the same comment, so I added a link table, comment_recipient

However, now I'm not sure how to select a list of recipients when selecting comments

AND

I'm not sure how to select comments based on a specific recipient

Here's what I have right now:

```
$sql = "SELECT c.*, [RECIPIENTS]
FROM comment AS c
JOIN user AS u2 ON c.sender = u2.id
WHERE c.type<=?";
if(isset($args['location'])) $sql .= " AND u2.location=?";
if(isset($args['userId'])) {
  if(isset($args['given'])) {
    $sql .= " AND c.sender=?";
  }else {
    $sql .= " AND c.recipient=?"; //need to see if in recipient list now?
  }
}
```

Edit:

Thanks to Barry's answer I've now got this:

```
$sql = "SELECT c.*
FROM comment_recipient AS cr
JOIN comment AS c ON c.id=cr.comment_id
JOIN user AS u2 ON c.sender = u2.id
WHERE c.type<=?";
if(isset($args['location'])) $sql .= " AND u2.location=?";
if(isset($args['userId'])) {
  if(isset($args['given'])) {
    $sql .= " AND c.sender=?";
  }else {
    $sql .= " AND cr.user_id=?";
  }
}
$sql .= " GROUP BY c.id";
$sql .= " ORDER BY c.date DESC";
$sql .= " LIMIT ?";
$sql .= " OFFSET ?";
```

I'll then use a second query to select recipients for each comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the following tables:

- User ( ID, Name )
- Comment ( ID,Name )
- CommentRecipient ( User_ID, Comment_ID ) - where these are both
  foreign keys to the table above.

Is it not as simple as:
To get recipients when you know the Comment query the linking table:

```
SELECT User_ID from CommentRecipient where Comment_ID= mycommentid;
```

and vice versa

```
SELECT Comment_ID from CommentRecipient where User_ID= myuserid;
```

Sorry if I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: For normal usage, I need the list of most recent comments, so for this I can just select the recipients in a second query(Unless there's a better way). I'll try rewriting this to query the link table IF I need to filter based on recipient. Did I get that right? :)

Comment: Yep that sounds right. If you have extra details in the comment table (like a time) then you can join that table in the query and add the time to the where clause.

Comment: If I join the comment table, won't that give me the same comment for each recipient? How could I group that in this case?

Comment: I meant join the comment table to limit the query.  What exactly are you trying to get?

Comment: I updated my question with my current query. Does that look ok? I am querying from the comment_recipient table, but grouping on comment id, so that I just get each comment once.